# Pandas- ValueError: Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found

Tags: python, pandas, csv, import

I am trying to copy some of the columns from the imported `csv` file to `selected.csv` but it gives me this error :

```
'ValueError: Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found: ['Status']';
```

It doesn't matter which column name I use it still won't work.
I tried printing the headers and it shows them normally, I even tried copying the column names from there so if there is maybe a whitespace I missed or something, but it still gives me the same error. I searched for the answer already but none of the ones I found were right for me.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as numpy
import csv as csv

path_to_import ='C:/Users/Amila/hello/Auftraege_ALSO_R00.csv'

import_file = pd.read_csv(path_to_import, sep=';',engine='python',encoding='utf-8-sig')

headers = pd.read_csv(path_to_import, index_col=0, nrows=0).columns.tolist()

columns = ['Status']

path_to_selected = 'C:/Users/Amila/hello/selected.csv'

pd.read_csv(path_to_import,usecols=columns).to_csv('selected.csv', index=False)
```

These are the printed column names:

```
['Auftragsdatum;"Auftrags-Nr.";"Ihre Referenz";"Auftragswert";"Auftragsstatus";"Lieferadresse";"Pos.";"Menge";"Art.Nr.";"Herst.Nr.";"Produktname";"Ihre Referenz (Position)";"Netto / Stk.";"Rechn.-Nr.";"Liefers.-Nr.";"Serien-Nr.";"Status";"Hersteller"']
```

Comment: you failed to pass the `sep` arg when reading the columns: `headers = pd.read_csv(path_to_import, index_col=0, nrows=0, sep-';').columns.tolist()` and in your last line: `pd.read_csv(path_to_import,usecols=columns, sep=';').to_csv('selected.csv', index=False)`

Comment: @EdChum thanks, that helps. I totally overlooked that. Just a quick question I corrected sep= for headers , and as I did so my first column name was gone. How do I correct that

Comment: Maybe your first column isn't the index column so you don't need `index_col=0`?

Comment: @EdChum thanks for all your help :) it works great now

Comment: I fixed what I needed. If you want you can :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have inconsistencies in your code:

```
pd.read_csv(path_to_import,usecols=columns).to_csv('selected.csv', index=False)
```

you didn't pass the same `sep` arg, it should be

```
pd.read_csv(path_to_import,usecols=columns, sep=';').to_csv('selected.csv', index=False)
```

additionally in your headers line:

```
headers = pd.read_csv(path_to_import, index_col=0, nrows=0).columns.tolist()
```

you've passed `index_col=0` this treats the first column as an index column which is inconsistent with your other lines so remove it:

```
headers = pd.read_csv(path_to_import, nrows=0).columns.tolist()
```