# Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found csv issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, import

My code for getting all column value from exl is given below :

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
col_list = ["storeName"]
df = pd.read_csv('/home/preety/Downloads/my_store.xlsx',usecols=col_list)
print("Column headings:")
print(df['storeName'])
```

Error i am getting :

```
File "/var/www/html/fulfilment-admin/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1232, in _validate_usecols_names
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found: ['CategoryName']
```

My excel is given below:
[image]

what i exactly want is i want all store_code in a list but when i trying to get it is returning me the error i dont know what i am doing wrong here can any one please help me related this . thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

To avoid such kind of errors specify separator argument `sep=` like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55514024/12385909

For those who has troubles with `usecols=` in `read_excel()` function - you need to specify here excel column names, e.g. `usecols=“A:E”` or `usecols=“A,C,E:F”`.

Comment: Please avoid using links and instead provide a code block. If you would like to reference another topic in SO, just leave a comment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
col_list = ["storeName"]
df = pd.read_csv('/home/preety/Downloads/my_store.xlsx',usecols=col_list)
print("Column headings:")
print(df['StoreName'])
```

The title of your column contains a capital "S", thus pandas is unable to locate "storeName" because it doesn't exist.

Comment: i updated the code but getting same error   ValueError: Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found: ['StoreName']

Comment: Any solution ?? stuck here