# Python : Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found error showing tried the below solutions given in Stack overflow

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Reading the CSV file using pandas to get specific column data with parameter usecols=[listofcolumnnames] which is 146 column names and it is showing 16 columns not found (  Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found error )

[Pandas- ValueError: Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55513128/pandas-valueerror-usecols-do-not-match-columns-columns-expected-but-not-found)

[https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-replace-single-with-double-quotes-in-list#:~:text=Use%20the%20str.,double%20quotes%20in%20each%20string](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-replace-single-with-double-quotes-in-list#:%7E:text=Use%20the%20str.,double%20quotes%20in%20each%20string).

I have tried this above given stackoverflow steps to solve the problem but not worked .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlUvk.jpg)

I have tried below methods to get the columns :

Method one:

```
file1DF=pd.read_csv(pathoffile[0],usecols=file1column)
print(file1DF)
```

Method Two:

```
file1DF=pd.read_csv(pathoffile[0],usecols=file1column,sep=',').columns.tolist()
print(file1DF)
```

Method Three:

```
e1=pd.read_csv(pathoffile[0],sep=',') 
e2=pd.DataFrame(exam1)
e3=e2[listofcolumns]
```

Method Four:

```
e1=pd.read_csv(pathoffile[0],sep=',') 
e2=pd.DataFrame(exam1)
e3=e2[listofcolumns]
jstrlist=Json.dumps(listofcolumns)
e3=e2[jstrlist]
```

but it shows keyerror and mentioned all 146 column names in double quotes in list of string '["146 column names"]'

Comment: It seams like 16 strings in the list do not exactly match the column names of the columns. Did you check special characters, white space etc.?

Comment: Please post sample CSV to reproduce the error.